# Registered Oracle 10g portlet but unable to place

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, portlet

I am using Oracle Portal 10.1.2.3.0 and have deployed a portlet application using JDeveloper, which says it succeeded.

I can see the application deployed in the correct OC4J container instance as well.

When I log in to the portal, I can see the providers registration record for this portlet.

1. Log in to portal
2. Click Edit on any page
3. Click Navigator
4. Click Providers tab
5. Click Registered Providers
6. Click Edit Registration on the portlet I previously deployed
7. Click the Connection tab
8. I see the providers URL: someserver/publications-dev/providers
9. I can access that URL and see the following output:

   Congratulations! You have successfully reached your Provider's Test Page.
   Recognizing Portlets...
   PublicationsNewsPortlet
   PublicationsNewsDetailPortlet
   PublicationsNewsDetailListPortlet
   PublicationsCareersPortlet
   PublicationsCareersDetailPortlet
   PublicationsCareersDetailListPortlet
   Recognizing component versions...
   ptlshare.jar version: 10.1.2.0.2
   pdkjava.jar version: 10.1.2.0.2

Yet, when I try to add the portlet to a page, searching for the portlet name "Careers Widget Portlet" or "PublicationsCareersPortlet" reveals nothing. This is defined in the provider.xml:

```
<name>PublicationsCareersPortlet</name>
<title>Careers Widget Portlet</title>
```

Can anyone give me a hint to what I might be missing? How can the Providers Test Paqe state that it recognizes the portlets but I cannot add them to a page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there was a problem with the registration - and I couldn't unregister the provider for some reason: This provider is not deletable. (WWC-43169).

Instead, I created a new registration and it now works.